# Sending a timed messege on discord with python

Tags: python, discord, message, timed

How do I send a message on discord channel from python? I tried YouTube videos they aren't working also I want the messages to be timed like after every 1 minute the message should go

```
import requests

token = '(my_token)'

channel_id = '(my_channel_id)'

message = 'thanks'


def sendmessage(token, channel_id, message):
    url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{}/messages'.format(channel_id)

    data = {
        'content': message
    }
    header = {'authorisation': token}

    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)

sendmessage(token, channel_id, message)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: maybe use special Python modules for discord instead of using `requests`. And module `discordpy` has [tasks.loops(seconds=...)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)

Comment: if you watched some video then you could add link for this video. Put it in question, not in comment - more people will see it, so more people may help you. Maybe video is old and it may not work if discord changed something. Or maybe you missted something from video.

Comment: to put  mulitiline code you have to use three ``` instead of single `

Comment: first you could use `print( r.text )` to see response from server. It can explain problem.

Comment: you have typo - it should be `z` in `authorization`

Comment: code works for me if I run discord in browser and copy my token from browser but not when I use bot token.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo - it should be `z` in `authorization`.

---

Your code works for me if I run discord in browser and copy my private token from browser
but it doesn't work with my bot token.

For bot it needs:

```
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bot {token}'}
```

Eventually it may need also `User-Agent` with bot's name (but I'm not sure if it is really required) .

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bot {token}'}
    'User-Agent': 'FurasBot (https://blog.furas.pl, v0.1)',
}
```

Found in: [sends messages to a discord channel using a bot via http POST](https://gist.github.com/ianklatzco/769d9e3a991dc2f443a2e105b0157117)

---

```
import requests

def send_message(token, channel_id, message, bot=False):

    if bot:
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Bot {token}'}
    else:
        headers = {'Authorization': token}

    url = f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages'

    payload = {'content': message}
    
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

    data = response.json()
    
    print(data)

# --- main ---

user_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  # 70 chars
bot_token  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'             # 59 chars

channel_id = 7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # 18 digits

message = 'Hello World!'

print('\n--- send as user ---\n')
send_message(user_token, channel_id, message)

print('\n--- send as bot ---\n')
send_message(bot_token, channel_id, message, bot=True)
```